# C# How can I use the external font? (.NET CF)

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, compact-framework

I want to use external font. 
but "PrivateFontCollection" is not supported at .NET Compact Framework

How can I use the font?

Comment: Have a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/760bcbee-2e50-4563-941a-b1f4c01724eb/embed-font-within-application-resources?forum=netfxcompact

Comment: @TripleEEE Thank you. but I read the contents before.. There is no solution.;(

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure if you did - next time just mention this in your question - we will know that you did read this already and maybe somebody will have a workaround instead of thinking you haven't searched yet.

Comment: I fear you have to copy the font to \Windows\fonts before you can use it. There seems no AddFontMemResourceEx on Windows CE I assume you are talking about a truetype font. Windows Mobile is based on Windows CE and not all Win32 API is supported.

Comment: @TripleEEE I wondered if there was a solution I did not know. I did not find the workaround to search. Thank you for your review and confirmation.

Comment: @josef I'll study more in that direction.